# Access the parent's data on child events in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two components, one inside the other one. I have a click event on the parent component that should change the data value of the child component.

```
<template>
   <div>
      .....
      .....
      <my-component
           :options="options">
      </my-component>
   </div>
.....
.....
</template>

<script>
...
...
data(){
}
methods:{
   clickEvent(array_from_child){
      this.array = array_from_child; //array is in my-component
   }
}
components:{
    ....
}
</script>
```

I want to trigger the clickEvent method on child's element change. how to do that?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to mutate an array in the child component, from the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're asking two different questions.

**First, accessing a child's data from its parent:**

If possible, you should pass the array to the child component using the child's `props`. Then simply change the array in the parent and any changes will be reflected in the child. If the array really needs to be in the child, then you can define a method to retrieve it.

```
<template>
    <child-component ref="child">
    </child-component>
</template>

methods: {
    onClick() {
        const myArray = this.$refs.child.getMyArray();
    }
}
```

And then, in the child

```
methods: {
    getMyArray() {
        return this.myArray;
    }
}
```

**Second, triggering a change in the parent from the child**

In this case, Flame's answer is most idiomatic. Emit a custom event in the child and listen for that event in the parent.

Comment: This works, however accessing the child's component reference breaks MVVM and its not recommended. Passing data from the parent to the child should be done through props, and the props should not be mutated by the child component.

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I said in the first paragraph.

Comment: can u update that code too which `daniel Ormeno'` said ?? @StephenThomas ? I can understand, but still couldn't make it work

Comment: Probably the best place to learn about how to use Vue props is the guide on the vuejs.org site. Vue's documentation is really quite good.

Answer (score 2):

When you are going from a child to a parent, you should use events:

```
{
   methods: {
        clickEvent()
        {
            this.$emit('click', mydata);
        }
}
```

So in your parent element, you can then attach your own callback to the emitted event like so:

```
<template>
    <my-child-component @click="theParentMethod" />
</template>
```

You could also use some reactivity by passing an object reference from the parent to the child, so if you change the object in the child, the parent can detect the changes. However this comes with some reactivity gotcha's, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html .

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think he is trying to change child data from the parent component.... not child -> parent, but parent >> child.. OP states: `I have a click event on the parent component that should change the data value of the child component.`

Comment: `passing an object reference from the parent to the child, so if you change the object in the child, the parent can detect the changes` This is bad practice and Vue will log a warning in the console if the child mutates the reference in the parent.

Comment: You're right and ive actually had mixed results with that, though I cant remember seeing a console warning related to that. I also cant seem to find the Vue docs reference where it is explained